# Divisão inteira devolvendo um resultado diferente do esperado

Tags: python, r, divisão, números

Eu estou tendo um problema com a divisão inteira em python e R.
A linguagem retorna um valor diferente do "correto" na divisão inteira do 327 por 3.27 e o resto(%) diferente de 0 nesses casos.
(A imagem é do python, mas em R se obtém os mesmos valores, conforme testei em minha máquina)
[image: Imagem]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que o computador não é muito preciso, é como você tentar armazenar 1/3 (não tem como pq é um número decimal infinito, então ele arredonda e perde a precisão).

Nesse [site](https://www.askpython.com/python/python-modulo-operator-math-fmod) explica melhor na sessão "Quick word on Floating Point Arithmetic Issues".

O que eu fiz foi multiplicar o valor por 100 e depois dividir, pois assim ele deixa de ser decimal e vira número inteiro.

[image: Exemplo do meu código]

Comment: Eu tava caçando alguma explicação como a desse site, valeu mesmo!